# How to write a specific part of a line in writeline

Tags: python

I have an error log, which I need to `writeline` the error code from.  The log usually ends in something like: `"Error, problem number: 9478389439"`

my code starts with:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.find('problem number:') >= 0:
      f.writeline(?????
```

I need to create a `list` with the error codes, and expand on it with other things.  This json is being generated for multiple analysis.  I can't just throw these on a `db` and find the results, I need a proper `writeline`.

Comment: Use the same `line.find` to get the index where the number starts and then slice? `f.writeline(line[line.find(...):])`

Comment: actually, what the expected output is? Is this whole/part/end of the log line?

Comment: just the error number, there are prior information on the line that I wish to avoid adding, a complete line looks like this:
2019-08-27 15:43:15 ERROR  (Blabla.java:144) -Error Number: 38633

There are almost 1 million lines in this log, and I need to list every code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.find('problem number:') >= 0:
        f.write(line.split('problem number:')[-1].strip())
```

Comment: Hey, I forgot to mention but the log has information prior to problem number, such as time and date etc, so I need to cut everything before problem number in addition to problem number itself, leaving just the number at the end of the phrase

Comment: f.writeline(line.split('problem number: ')[-1].strip())
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writeline'

Comment: can you put all your code? i'm not sure if line is a string or not

Comment: @MatheusRevoredo Indeed, it has only `write` for a single line or `writelines` for multiple lines. Note that `write` does not automatically add a line break.

Comment: yep you can do with write

Comment: with open("numerosLogs.log", "w") as f:
    f.write('Quantidade de processos adicionados a cada Cidade:\n')
    for k, v in adicionados.items():
        f.writelines(k + ' ' + str(v) + '\n')
        
    for line in lines:
        if line.find('FATAL') >= 0:
                f.writeline(line, '\n')
    for line in lines:
      if line.find('Quantidade de processos Total PJe 1grau a carregar') >= 0:
                    f.writeline(line.split('a carregar')[-1].strip())

Comment: thats the end of the code basically since I am doing other things on it, the error message only appears in the last line which is the one you gave me

Comment: if you want to append all the lines, you should use: with open("numerosLogs.log", "a" ) if "numerosLogs.log" is not a new file